# Tenses to pair with participial phrases

Tags: tenses, participial-phrases

I am teaching about participial phrases these days, and all examples I am able to find online have the phrases paired with simple tenses. For example:

> Removing his glasses, Kent Clark quickly **put** on his cape.
>
> Running up to the boy, the dog **hopes** that he will have a treat.
>
> Eaten by mosquitos, we **wished** that we have stayed at home.

I seldom see participial phrases paired with a continuous tense, thus I want to know if there's a rule to this.

For example:

> Watching the crime happening, I **was calling** the police for help.

Is this possible we use the past continuous for the clause, or we must use the simple past tense?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case that you *must* use the simple aspect in a clause following a participial phrase. If you want to convey that the action or state of the verb was ongoing, then the continuous aspect is appropriate. For example:

- Walking into the exam room, I *was hoping* that I'd studied hard
  enough.
- Woken by the dog's barking, we *were trying* to get back to sleep when
  suddenly the phone rang.

The use of the continuous aspect in *'Watching the crime happening, I was calling the police for help* conveys to me that the speaker was having trouble getting through to the police, i.e. that the calling or the attempt to get a connection took place over an unspecified amount of time.

Comment: It is true that I am trying to express how there's trouble connecting the police. And your explanation has fully cleared my doubt. Thank you!

Comment: @Miss Joey. I think most native speakers would say "_I was trying to call the police_" and not just _"I was calling the police"_.